# No access rights in Docker Container when using SLES15 and *Suse Container

Tags: linux, docker, sles

I am running Docker 18.09.6 on SLES15 (GNU/Linux 4.12.14). When starting any suse container leap/tumbleweed or sle15 I do not have proper access rights to see `ls -l`. Other Container Images like Alpine and Ubuntu work without a problem.
In both cases I am `id -u = 0` and root according to `whoami`.

Sample:

```
275b1cf2bd20:/ # ls -l
ls: cannot access 'sbin': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'sys': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'usr': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'proc': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'bin': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'tmp': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'selinux': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'boot': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'home': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'root': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'dev': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'var': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'run': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'lib64': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'opt': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'srv': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'mnt': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'lib': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'etc': Operation not permitted
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? bin
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? boot
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? dev
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? etc
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? home
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? lib
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? lib64
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? mnt
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? opt
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? proc
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? root
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? run
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? sbin
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? selinux
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? srv
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? sys
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? tmp
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? usr
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? var
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue when I was trying to run SLES based container on different host machine ( i.e. host machine having different OS than SLES)

If docker image and host machine are based on same OS, then it should not have permission issue with `ls -l` or `ls -n`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30907861)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be linked to an update in Linux kernel version in opensuse:leap, debian:bullseye, etc: all further version of these OS are also concerned.

github.com user tianon recommend updating "*Docker, runc, and likely libseccomp on your host.*"
source: https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/465

Upgrading of libseccomp to version 2.5.2 solved the same problem on my side.

source: https://github.com/seccomp/libseccomp/blob/main/CHANGELOG