# Docker + SLES15 : Unable to access files inside docker container : ls: cannot access '<directory/file name>': Operation not permitted

Tags: docker, docker-compose, suse, sles

I am new to docker and trying to create  docker file from  SLES 15 base image:

```
FROM <base image - SLES 15 >

LABEL <label> \
    Version="1.0"
```

In docker-compose.yml , I have mentioned :

```
working_dir: $PWD
volumes:
      - $PWD/../../:$PWD/../../
```

When I start docker container, I am not able to access any file or directory with following error:

```
 ls: cannot access '<directory/file name>': Operation not permitted 
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? <directory-name>
```

I tries possible solutions suggested like :

1. Setting file permissions with chown/chmod
2. Disable selinux

Any idea about root cause of this issue and possible solution?

Similar issue from stackoverflow : [No access rights in Docker Container when using SLES15 and *Suse Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69786640/no-access-rights-in-docker-container-when-using-sles15-and-suse-container)

Comment: if following on the thread you've linked to, have you tried doing a similar operation on another distro image like debian

Comment: I did try with CentOS7 based image and didn't see any issue there. I could access files/directories using "ls -n" with no permission issue

Comment: maybe its a user permission issue? try using the `id` command with each image to see with what user are you running in them

Comment: I did try  permission settings using chown/chmod.  I have verified that ``id`` ( user and group ) is 0  and user is root inside container. I also tried to set it specific to user group of my local machine where I am trying to run container. I am still getting ``ls: cannot access '<directory/file name>': Operation not permitted `` when trying ``ls -n`` or ``ls -l``

Comment: I tried to start container with same UID and GID of an host machine : 'docker-compose run --user 1000:1000 <image-name> bash'. even with this facing same issue.

Comment: maybe try with `--priveledged` and `-u 0`?

Comment: I updated my  docker file ``RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash -u 1000 -U dockerbuilduser && \
    echo "dockerbuilduser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/dockerbuilduser && \
    mkdir /home/dockerbuilduser/.gradle && \
    chown 1000:1000 /home/dockerbuilduser && \
    chmod 777 -R /home/dockerbuilduser && \
    chmod 0400 /etc/sudoers.d/dockerbuilduser

USER dockerbuilduser
``   Created user with same uid of host machine user and also assigned ownership. Still when I  do `cd /home/dockerbuilduser` and then `ls -l` I get permission error. same error for newly created folder as well

Comment: Yes after running container with `--privileged` flag. I could run `ls -l` without permission error. However as per my understanding it is not recommended to use privileged containers. How can I solve this issue without privileged container.

Comment: that's good progress! to what user\privildges did it achieve? have you tried changing ownership to `nobody:nogroup`? do you have a requirement to use this exact distro?

Comment: Yes. For privileged mode - When I don't add any user in Dockerfile, It defaults to root with output as `drwxrwxrwx 1 0 0 27 Jan 24 17:24 <folder-name>` ( i.e. uid and gid as 0 and user as root ) . If I add dockerbuilduser then it's `drwxrwxrwx 1 1000 1000 27 Jan 24 17:24 <folder-name>` ( i.e. uid and gid as 1000 and user as dockerbuilduser). Sorry I didn't understand your point about changing ownership to `nobody:nogroup`. Yes I have requirement to use this exact distro.

Comment: with the `dockerbuilduser` user, did it work?

Comment: I could deduce possible issue today. Actually It was my mistake to try running SLES based docker container on CentOS based host machine. That was the reason of permission issue. When I use SLES based host machine there are no permission issues. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks Noam for all your inputs. It helped me to understand the docker concepts.

Comment: could you elaborate on the difference in permissions? why would two contradict if both based on the linux kernel? please add this to the final answer

Comment: See response https://stackoverflow.com/a/71647888/6747280 : update libseccomp on host to at least 2.5.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting permission issues because I was running SLES based docker container inside CentOS based host machine. If I use SLES based host machine, I could run the container without any permission issue.

Comment: Is there another solution? Is it possible to run such an container?

Answer (score 0):

in my case I fixed it by upgrading docker to latest version.

[reference link.](https://travis-ci.community/t/unable-to-access-file-structure-of-docker-container-when-running-in-travis/11229)